# How to intercept WebView Navigating event in ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

My app has a WebView for displaying some contact information. It has a link to a website that I want to load externally using `Device.OpenUri()`. I'm using [FreshMvvm](http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/freshmvvm-mvvm-framework-designed-xamarin-forms/) and I want to intercept the `Navigating` event from the WebView in the ViewModel and cancel the default action which would load the external page into the WebView.

I've tried using the [Corcav.Behaviors](https://github.com/corradocavalli/Corcav.Behaviors) plugin which does call my ViewModel command:

```
        <WebView
            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            Source="{Binding WebViewSource}">
              <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:BehaviorCollection>
                    <b:EventToCommand
                        EventName="Navigating"
                        Command="{Binding NavigatingCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/> <!-- what goes here -->
                </b:BehaviorCollection>
              </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </WebView>
```

But I'm not sure what the CommandParameter should be - I need the URI of the link that was tapped, and I don't know how to then prevent the default behaviour from occurring.

Is this the best approach or should I be looking at an alternative?

Comment: No need to specify the CommandParameter, NavigatingCommand should be of type DelegateCommand<ItemTappedEventArgs>, the tappedItem is the item property of the argument.

Comment: @rauland when I use that approach, i.e. leaving out the CommandParameter, I get nothing passed as the parameter - even when specifying `object` as the parameter type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having revisited this recently for another project I stumbled across [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440569/132599). The updated XAML is:

```
<WebView
    x:Name="webView"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    Source="{Binding WebViewSource}">
    <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:BehaviorCollection>
            <behaviors:EventToCommand
                EventName="Navigating"
                Command="{Binding NavigatingCommand}"
                PassEventArgument="True" />
        </behaviors:BehaviorCollection>
    </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
</WebView>
```

The code in the ViewModel, that matches the tapped url against a list of valid options before opening the link in the device's browser, is:

```
public Command<WebNavigatingEventArgs> NavigatingCommand
{
    get
    {
        return navigatingCommand ?? (navigatingCommand = new Command<WebNavigatingEventArgs>(
            (param) =>
            {
                if (param != null && -1 < Array.IndexOf(_uris, param.Url))
                {
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(param.Url));
                    param.Cancel = true;
                }
            },
            (param) => true
            ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t navigate with a WebView, you must use a custom render (hybridwebview).
Here is an explanation:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/

Comment: Maybe you've misinterpreted what I'm trying to achieve. I want to intercept the `Navigating` event that is triggered when tapping on a link in a WebView and then open the associated URL in an external browser. I'm not trying to use the link to navigate within the app.