# Suppress links in WebView

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I have a web page that I would like to display in a Web View in my app. But the page has links. Is there any way I can suppress all links on a page when it is being displayed in a WebView.

Edit - 9/25

What I really mean by suppressing is that I dont want any of the links to display. So in my responsive application, all my links show up as a hamburger menu when I view it in a mobile. I dont want that to even display. Is that possible.

Comment: you can intercept the navigation events and cancel them

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to webview's `Navigating` event and set `e.Cancel = true`.

There is a very good code sample in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057143/7292772) on how to implement this with MVVM support. You can also refer this [link](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/how-to-handle-xamarin-forms-webview-internal-navigations/) for a more simple example.

**EDIT 1 - as per updated question**

You can do the same by using javascript injection to show or hide elements from DOM in `WebView`. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644422/7292772) that does something similar to intercept clicks on all elements.

Comment: Thank you Sharada. I will modify my question a little. Basically I dont want the links to be displayed in my Android or iOS app.

Comment: You can use javascript injection to remove the elements from DOM - you can refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644422/7292772