# How to intercept Xamarin's WebView javascript API calls

Tags: xamarin, webview, interceptor

We are trying to intercept in Xamarin Get API calls done in WebView.
The reason we do it - is we want to implement such flow:
for Example:

- there is index.html that we are navigating to in newly opened WebView in Xamarin. And this index.html has let's say 2 resources: 1) abc.css and 2) def.js files. When WebView container will load index.html it will try to load this to files by making two Get API call, and we want to create interceptor on Xamarin side which will check: 1) if there is abc.css exists in Xamarin app 2) if yes stop loading it from server, but provide it to WebView instead.

Can we create such kind of interceptor in Xamarin?

I did my research and I found that Xamarin can intercept [Navigating events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560415/how-to-intercept-webview-navigating-event-in-viewmodel), but this is very different to Get API calls.